# Mysql Generate simple stored function

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I've been struggling for about an hour trying to get a simple stored function to work in mysql. I made the below simple example and I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION hello(id INT) 
RETURNS VARCHAR
BEGIN
    RETURN 'Works';
END;

hello(2);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
>           RETURN 'Works';
>       END' at line 3

I'm pretty sure this is a "dumb" question but I'm not a sql guy whatsoever and desperately need to put together a set of functions to build a custom report

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`VARCHAR` is not a valid datatype: you need to give it a length, like `VARCHAR(5)`:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION hello(id INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(5)
BEGIN
    RETURN 'Works';
END;
//
```

Also, please note that your existing function could be simplified as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION hello(id INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(5)
    RETURN 'Works';
```

The `BEGIN` keyword comes into play when the function contains *compound statments*,  like declarations, loops and so on. Also, as commented by Raymond Nijland, there is no need to specify the `DELIMITER` since there is a single statement in the function.

Reference: [MySQL `CREATE PROCEDURE` and `CREATE FUNCTION` Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Comment: As single MySQL  statements/programs does not require `DELIMITER //` the simplified version would be  `CREATE FUNCTION hello(id INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(5)
    RETURN 'Works';` -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5E95nojBDePR2evtwKdwXU/0 ..